# Orthogonal projection question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Consider the (orthogonal) projection $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ onto the plane $x - y + z = 0$.
>
> - (a) Find the standard matrix $[T]_S$ for $T$.
> - (b) Find a new basis $B$ so that $[T]_B$ is rather simple.

How do I do this question?
I created an orthogonal basis and projected $(x,y,z)$.
My result was

$[T]_s=\begin{bmatrix}11/18 & 7/18 & -2/9\\
7/18 & 11/18 & 2/9\\
-2/9 & 2/9 & 4/9
\end{bmatrix}$

and what about part b? Do I make the new basis equal to the orthogonal one I found when solving part a? and is $[T]_B$ a $3 \times 3$ unit matrix?

Comment: Part a) doesn't look right. Remember the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$.

Comment: In the first part you got to the take the standard basis, as @DanRust said... afterward, just pick an Orthogonal Basis with two vectors already in the plane... and lastly your matrix will indeed look *almost*/*very close* to the unit matrix... but not exactly

Comment: The answer to part two can’t be the unit matrix because the image of $T$ is only two-dimensional.

Comment: Check your work. For any projection $P$, you should have $P^2=P$. Is this true of $[T]_S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix is wrong. An easy sanity check is that a matrix representing an orthogonal projection should be symmetric with trace equal to the dimension of the space you are projecting onto (in your case, two).

A unit normal vector to your plane is $v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and so the projections of the standard basis vectors are given by

$$ T(e_1) = e_1 - \left<e_1, v \right>v = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} \\ -\frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}, \\
T(e_2) = e_2 - \left<e_2, v \right>v = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} \end{pmatrix}, \\
T(e_3) = e_3 - \left<e_3, v \right>v = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{2}{3} \end{pmatrix} $$

and so

$$ [T]_S = \begin{pmatrix} [Te_1]_S & [Te_2]_S & [Te_3]_S \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\ -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3} \end{pmatrix}. $$

If you pick an orthonormal basis $(v_1,v_2)$ for the plane $x - y + z = 0$ and take $v_3 = v$, then with respect to the new basis, the matrix will become

$$ [T]_{(v_1,v_2,v_3)} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can you please explain why the last matrix ([T]b) is like that?

Comment: You have $T(v_1) = v_1, T(v_2) = v_2$ (since $v_i$ are already in the plane you are projecting onto) and $T(v_3) = 0$ (since $v_3$ is orthogonal to the plane you are projecting onto).